# Is there a way to move my iOS Simulator app data from one simulator (iPhone 7) to another (iPad Pro 12.9)?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have an app built and running in my iPhone 7 simulator using Xcode 8. It's loaded up in the simulator and I've loaded the app with stored data now stored locally.

When I run that same app on my iPad Pro 12.9 simulator, it acts like a fresh device and has none of the stored data in it for my app.

Is there a way to have all of the simulators use the same app storage? Or at least any easy way to move apps between them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Go to **~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices**. (Library folder is hidden generally. Unhide the folder with this command in terminal - **defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES** and restart the Finder).
- You will find the bunch of folders specific to the simulator at the mentioned path. Also find plist, named ***device_set.plist***, which has the entry of all the available simulators.

[image]

- Find the ids of the source and destination simulators you are interested in under **Root->DefaultDevices->com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-XX-X** (XX-X - OS version that you run your simulator on.)
- Once you find the ids, search the folder with that name in the above-mentioned path.
- The simulator folder will contain **data** and **device.plist**.
- Copy the data folder from source simulator and replace it in the destination simulator.
- That's it! If your destination simulator is open, just restart it and it should reflect the data of source simulator.

Comment: Worked perfect! Thank you!

Comment: This has seriously saved me so much trouble. Thanks!